# Find the difference between two times and multiply that by a value

Tags: string, excel, time, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I wish to calculate the difference between two times multiplied by a value in another column. My columns are like this:

```
       Column A                Column B             Column C
1    09:00 - 21:00                 2
```

I want my Column C to return `24`, since the time difference in Column A is 12 hours, and the multiplier in Column B is `2`.

Comment: The easier way to do this would be to parse out `09:00 - 21:00` into two separate columns when you read it in from file.  And if you're doing this entirely in Excel, then this **definitely** is not the way to go

Comment: In case it is not obvious in the answer below, the difference between times in Excel has units of **days**.  You will want to multiply by 24 to get to hours.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=B1*24*(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+2,LEN(A1))-LEFT(A1,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which uses `TIMEVALUE()` in case your formatting around the hyphen includes whitespace.

```
=(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)))*24*B1
```

As stated in the comment up above, you will do better to have these in separate columns, but these formulas work nonetheless.

If you want to subtract times that are split across midnight (00:00), you can force clock arithmetic using the `MOD(XXX, 24)` formula.  This will prevent negatives.  It also means that the difference can never be greater than 24 (before multiplying by column B).

```
=MOD((TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)))*24,24)*B1
```

Comment: Thank you...
But when I try to change the column A to 21:00 - 1:00, it will show negative value...how to let the result return 4?

Comment: At this point you will have to make some assumptions about what values are possible.  Since we are doing "clock" arithmetic, it is not as simple as taking the absolute value.  One option is to look for a negative and add 24 before multiplying by column B.  Another option (if we agree times cannot be more than 24 hours apart), is to use the modulo operator to force "clock" arithmetic.  That formula would be `=MOD((TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)))*24,24)*B1`